# How to hide UploadFile button in Files Related list

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, related-list, chatter-file

We need to disable the Upload Files button in the Files related list and force the users to use Chatter feed to upload files. 
I cannot remove the Upload Files button from the related list by config way thus I am trying to remove the button using the visualforce page. 
I have added a visualforce page in the parent detailed page, the idea is upon the load of the page, a java script will run to hide the button. 
But unfortunately I cannot get the upload file button hidden.

My javascript code is: 
I get the first alert "loading..." but not the 2nd alert. 
I tried both getElementsById and getElementsByName to hide the button nothing works. 
Can you please suggest what is wrong with the code.

```
    <script> 
    var previousOnload = window.onload; 
    window.onload = function() 
    {
     if (previousOnload) { previousOnload(); } 
     alert('loading...'); 
     alert(document.getElementsById("RFLNewFile" )[0]);
     window.parent.document.getElementsByName("NewFile" )[0].style.display='hidden';
    } 
    </script>
```

Comment: It will better a create a visualforce page which will list all the files, without any upload File button. That will be must cleaner approach. Secondly, using javascript to make "upload file" hidden is some kind of fragile.

Comment: Thanks Santanu. Files data model is bit hard any examples? Thanks.

Comment: I think there is no properties like.           ` style.display=hidden`  you may use `style.visibility = "hidden"` or `style.display=none`

Comment: is this Lightning or Classic? If Classic, use VF page with `apex:detail` as only component and jQuery to find the Upload Files button and then hide it using .css().hide()